# Powershell: sort out latest files

Tags: powershell

I have a folder with hundreds of XML files. They have ID-Version strings in text content. I need to sort out latest files of each ID (by creation date).
I wrote powershell script which gets 1 arg (folderName).
There's also file with list of latest ID-Version strings (same name as folder)

```
$folder =  $Args[0] 
$lines = Get-Content -Path .\$($folder).txt
Set-Location -Path .\$folder
New-Item -ItemType directory -Force -Path .\latest

$lines | ForEach-Object {
    Get-ChildItem -Path .\*.xml  | Select-String -Pattern $_ -SimpleMatch -CaseSensitive | Sort-Object CreationTime -Descending | Select-Object -First 1 | Move-Item -Destination .\latest
}
```

The problem is that script doesn't move latest version. It picks random one. It might be because ID-Version key-string appears many times in XML.

Also this script runs really slow (comparing to .bat, which does similar task).
Maybe there's something that can speed it up?

UPD: I also need to remove duplicate lines from txt file. How to do that?

UPD2:
Problem might be because sort-object can't be applied to search result.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path .\*.xml | Select-String -Pattern $_ -SimpleMatch -CaseSensitive | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending
```

results in

```
IgnoreCase : False
LineNumber : 214
Line       : <RegNumber>50:08:0050434:983-50/008/2017-2</RegNumber>
Filename   : 351.xml
Path       : C:\ren\351.xml
Pattern    : 50:08:0050434:983-50/008/2017-2
Context    :
Matches    : {}


IgnoreCase : False
LineNumber : 216
Line       : <Name> № 50:08:0050434:983-50/008/2017-2 от 06.07.2017</Name>
Filename   : 351.xml
Path       : C:\ren\351.xml
Pattern    : 50:08:0050434:983-50/008/2017-2
Context    :
Matches    : {}


IgnoreCase : False
LineNumber : 218
Line       : <Name> № 50:08:0050434:983-50/008/2017-2 от 06.07.2017</Name>
Filename   : 298.xml
Path       : C:\ren\298.xml
Pattern    : 50:08:0050434:983-50/008/2017-2
Context    :
Matches    : {}


IgnoreCase : False
LineNumber : 88
Line       : <RegNumber>50:08:0050434:983-50/008/2017-2</RegNumber>
Filename   : 298.xml
Path       : C:\ren\298.xml
Pattern    : 50:08:0050434:983-50/008/2017-2
Context    :
Matches    : {}


IgnoreCase : False
LineNumber : 216
Line       : <RegNumber>50:08:0050434:983-50/008/2017-2</RegNumber>
Filename   : 298.xml
Path       : C:\ren\298.xml
Pattern    : 50:08:0050434:983-50/008/2017-2
Context    :
Matches    : {}
```

however 298.xml is newer (and is supposed to appear earlier than 351.xml)

Comment: Can you provide an example of the xml ?

Comment: Id-Version = 77-77-04/115/2012-026. Example:

<Registration >
<ID_Record>245924880777</ID_Record>
<RegNumber>77-77-04/115/2012-026</RegNumber>
<Type>001001000000</Type>
<Name>Собственность, № 77-77-04/115/2012-026 от 20.11.2012</Name>

Comment: Please edit that into your question, not in the comments @megapotz

Comment: While you iterate `$lines` you do ***not*** use the current item `$_` or `$PSItem` for the Get-ChildItem but use Select-String what stringifies the result removing the properties. A string has no CreationTime.